# MSBuild creates BAT file, call it and delete it immediately, how can I see BAT content?

Tags: msbuild

I'm diagnosing a Visual Studio project building problem, and I want to see what MSBuild.exe actually does. However, from Procmon, I see MSBuild creates BAT file, call it and delete it immediately, then how can I see that BAT's content?

For example, real BAT command is hidden inside `tmpd60d571fd9d549e5b2b31bb1f2ba51a7.exec.cmd`.

```
"C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe"  /Q /C C:\Users\win7evn\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpd60d571fd9d549e5b2b31bb1f2ba51a7.exec.cmd
```

MSBuild.exe writes cl.exe, link.exe, Prebuild/Postbuild custom commands etc into those temporary bat files. Specifically, I want to see how exactly MSBuild is calling my custom commands and how does he pass parameters to me from within a bat file.

[image: Procmon showing MSBuild activity]

The ideal way, I think, may be some tools that can intercept file deleting operation, and make a backup(copy) of that file, so we can investigate the "deleted" files later. Procmon only records ReadFile and WriteFile byte count, but not their byte content, so I think Procmon is not enough.

### ==== Update ====

According to stijn's answer(env-var `MSBUILDPRESERVETOOLTEMPFILES=1`), I tried it on VS2019 with success. The content in the xxx.exec.cmd is like this:

[image]

Two things to note:

1. We don't need to pass `/verbosity:d` parameter.
2. On VS2010, the MSBuild version may be too old, no effect.

Final comment: I think this feature of "seeing true .bat content" is critical, because, I may use many macros in my Custom-build/Prebuild/Postbuild commands, like `$(ProjectDir)`, `$(Configuration)`, or even my own defined macros of any name, so I need a global view of the macro expansion result, instead of checking each macro from VSIDE UI one by one(so many mouse clicking and time consuming) . The .bat content is the exact global view I need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Msbuid creates .cmd files when it runs the `Exec` task, depending on what problem you are diagnosing it might be enough to just know what statements are added in those files, which can be found here: https://github.com/dotnet/msbuild/blob/main/src/Tasks/Exec.cs.

Otherwise set the `MSBUILDPRESERVETOOLTEMPFILES` environment variable to 1 so the files do not get deleted, then run with `/v:D` to see which files were created.